# How to get length of first line in Edittext android?

Tags: android

I have a multi lines Edittext with a text (don't content "\n"), a font size (sp) 
and the length of text > Edittext.width().
I want to get length of the first line in EditText.
How can I do it?

[You can see the photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGktV.png)

Answer (score 4):

One option could be to read the text and then get the index of the newline character, which is essentially the length of the string prior to it:

```
int firstLineLength = myEditText.getText().toString().indexOf("\n");
```

As an alternative, if you ever need to do this with other lines you can simply split the whole string based on the newline character:

```
String[] lines = myEditText.getText().toString().split("\n");
```

**EDIT**

Keep in mind that indexOf() will return -1 if an occurrence is not found. So if your EditText has one and only one string, you'll get a -1 line length so be prepared to check against that:

```
int lineEndIndex = myEditText.getText().toString().indexOf("\n");
int firstLineLength;
if(lineEndIndex == -1) {
   firstLineLength = myEditText.getText().toString().length();
} else {
   firstLineLength = lineEndIndex;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But my text don't content "\n". How can do that?

Comment: @DanhNguyen you mean there's only one line then? See my edit for that

Comment: Sory, That 's not what I want.
Example:
I have a text :
"aaaaaabbcdefgjkglglg
 efkglglglglglglglglglgljkf
 iksssfkfkf"
But it don't content "\n". I want to get "aaaaaabbcdefgjkglglg" (the first line).

Comment: So it's up to the first space? You can still use my method. If you just want the number of characters on the first row I'm not sure what you'd do with that, but you might have to do some calculation where you get the width of the EditText and divide it by the width of a character to get the number of characters it can hold.

Comment: Yes, I want the number of characters on the first row.
I use a code:
Num of char = (int) (DeviceUtil.convertPx2Sp(getActivity(), EditText.getWidth())/fontsize)

But it get wrong number of character